# interrupt LineSegment at given position

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Given the below vertices positions I'm drawing a square using THREE.LineSegments (or even by a simple THREE.Line.)

**vertices:**

```
path.vertices = [
        new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ), new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ), new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ), new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 ), new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 )
    ];
```

what's the best way to add holes/interruptions with specific size to the square corners? *(or any parts of the square lines)*

**expected result:**

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.min.js"></script>

<header>
 <style>
  body canvas{
   width: 100%,
   height: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
 </style>
</header>

<body>
</body>

<script>
var renderer, camera, scene, controls;


function initRenderer(){
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 renderer.setClearColor(0x264d73, 1);
}

function initScene(){
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
}

function initCamera(){
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 camera.position.set( 0, 50, 0 );
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 scene.add(camera);
}

function initLights(){
 var aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xD0D0D0, 0.5);
 scene.add(aLight);
}

////// Initializers ////////////////////////

function add_path(){
 path = new THREE.Geometry();
 path.vertices = [
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ), new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 3.4000015258789062 ), new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10.600006103515625, 0, 10.600006103515625 ), new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 10.600006103515625 ), new THREE.Vector3( 3.4000015258789062, 0, 3.4000015258789062 )
 ];
 
 
 
 var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff00f0,
    });

 var line = new THREE.LineSegments( path, material );
    scene.add(line);
 camera.lookAt(line.position);
 camera.position.x += 7;
 camera.position.y -= 30;
 camera.position.z += 5;
}

///// Mouse events ////////

///// Main /////////
function main(){
 initRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initScene();
 initCamera(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 initLights();
 add_path();
 animate();
}

function animate(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 render_all();
}

function render_all(){
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe the `.intersectBox()` method of [Ray](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Ray)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a solid squared object with the same background color, outline it in red.

Once you have this object placed in your target, assuming that you are in a 2D world and the camera is static, place it in a way that is bit "closer" to the camera.

Comment: it's just a simple prototype of a square cell ..I will then use it on every cell in a grid filled with squares (or hexagons)..It's all in 3D but I didn't want to make this too complex so it's less confusing.. .